# Wrap nodes with certain id under same parent

Tags: xslt

I would like to transform the following HTML code

```
<div id="pg-1">
    <div id="pgc-1">
        <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
    </div>

    <div id="pgc-2">
        <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="pg-2">
    <div id="pgc-3">
        <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
    </div>

    <div id="pgc-4">
        <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

into this

```
<section id="pg-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="pgc-1">
                <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
            </div>

            <div id="pgc-2">
                <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="pg-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="pgc-3">
                <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
            </div>

            <div id="pgc-4">
                <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I was able to get this XSLT document working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="//div[starts-with(@id, 'pgc-')]">       
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </div>
        </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="//div[starts-with(@id, 'pg-')]">
       <section>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
       </section>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't produce exactly what I want: in particular, it does wrap the elements with id `pgc` inside the container, but it doesn't group them into only one parent. This is what is outputted right now (for each section):

```
<section id="pg-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="pgc-1">
                <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="pgc-2">
                <div class="test">Hello World!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

As a summary of what I would like to do:

- Change the tag name of all elements with `id` attribute starting with `pg-` to `section` (I should copy all attributes to the new element)
- Wraps all child elements whose div with `id` attribute starts with `pgc-` under the same parent node `.container > .row` (I should copy all attributes to the new element)

Comment: The output that you show is not well-formed (no closing tags for `section`).

Comment: You're right, but it was just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing* you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[starts-with(@id, 'pg-')]">
    <section>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--
(*) With only a (flawed) example and no stated rules, all one can do is guess.

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements. Why doesn't the above work for you?

Comment: It works, but it doesn't copy all attributes of the elements with id `pg-` over the new `section` element. It copies only the `id` attribute

Comment: @Stefano How about now?

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you